# how to subtract a value of a key in python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm learning python and I'm trying to use this function I built and its not working. The function is not changing a single value in the dictionary as it is working now, although it should. I'd like to get some help

```
def delete_product(diction):
    product_to_delete = raw_input()
    for key,value in diction.items():
        if key == product_to_delete:
            value = value - 1
            if (value == 0):
                del diction[key]
            print "removed"
            raw_input()
    print "we couldnt remove the product because it does not exist"
    raw_input()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistake in this code snippet:

```
value = value - 1
if (value == 0):
    del diction[key]
```

Instead of modifying value in the dictionary, you are only modifying local value. So, this function will delete the required entry only when value happens to be 1.

You can modify it as follows or any variation of it:

```
    if value == 1:
        del diction[key]
        break
    else:
        diction[key] = value - 1
```

Moreover, please note that you have to break out of the for loop once the entry is deleted from the dictionary. If you modify the dictionary while you are iterating it, the iterator will not work after that. If you want to delete multiple keys in one iteration, first get list of all keys to be deleted within the loop and delete after the loop.